# Updating state on first render only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Using react-native, I'm creating sub-Components within the parent `App` and providing their position to the array `this.state.objLocation` within the parent `App`.

I can get the initial location data into the array straight after the render, but because my subcomponents are draggable, each time they re-render on drag, it adds a new position object to the array.

I'd like to avoid this, and I thought that creating `this.state = { firstRender: true }` in the constructor and then using `componentDidMount = () => { this.setState({ firstRender: false }) }` after the first render would allow me to create a 'gate' to stop the addition of the extra position objects.

I can see that if I comment out `//componentDidMount = () => { this.setState({ firstRender: false }) }` then I will get multiple entries to my array but if it's included in the class I get absolutely none.

So possibly my interpretation of the render lifecycle and `componentDidMount` is incorrect?

Here is my code.

// App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { View, Text, } from 'react-native';
import styles from './cust/styles';
import Draggable from './cust/draggable';

const dataArray = [{num: 1,id: 'A',},{num: 2,id: 'B',},{num: 3,id: 'Z',}]

export default class Viewport extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dID  : null,
            objLocation: [],
            firstRender: true,
        };
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
                <View style={styles.draggableContainer}>
                    <Text>Draggable Container</Text> {dataArray.map( d => { return(
                    <Draggable 
                        id={d.id} 
                        onLayout={ e=> this.onLayout(e)} 
                        onPanResponderGrant={(dID) =>this.setState({ dID })} 
                        onPanResponderRelease={() => this.setState({dID: null})} /> ) })}
                        <View style={[styles.findPoint ]} /> 
                </View>
                <View style={styles.infoBar}>
                    <Text>{this.state.dID ? this.state.dID : ''}</Text>{this.compFrame()}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    onLayout = (e) => {
      if ( e && this.state.firstRender) {
        const n = e.nativeEvent.layout;
            const position = {
              width: n.width,
              height: n.height,
              x: n.x,
              y: n.y
            }
        console.log(position);
        this.setState({
          objLocation: this.state.objLocation.concat([position])
        });
      }
    }
    componentWillMount = () => {
      console.log("START");
    }
    compFrame = () => {
      return(
        this.state.objLocation.map( d => {<View style={[styles.findPoint2,{left: d.x, top: d.y, width: d.width, height: d.height} ]} ></View>})
        )
    }
    componentDidMount = () => {
      this.setState({firstRender: true })
      console.log(this.state.objLocation.length);
    }
}
```

// Draggable

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, PanResponder, Animated } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

class Draggable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
    };
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        this.props.onPanResponderGrant(this.props.id);
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([ null, {
          dx: this.state.pan.x,
          dy: this.state.pan.y,
        },
      ]),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        Animated.spring(this.state.pan, { toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 } }).start();
        this.props.onPanResponderRelease();
      },
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View
        onLayout={ (e) => this.props.onLayout(e) }
        {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), styles.circleAlt, styles.position]}>
        <Text style={styles.textAlt}>Drag me!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.textNum}>{this.props.id}</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.onLayout(this.props.dragEvent)
  }
}
export default Draggable;
```

// Output of console.log

```
START xxx
0
{width:108,height:108,x:133.5,y:376.5}
{width:108,height:108,x:133.5,y:78.5}
{width:108,height:108,x:133.5,y:227.5}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to include the output of `console.log` and Sambhav Jain pointed out an error which I have edited and removed.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the firstRender state in onLayout function

```
     onLayout = (e) => {
          if ( e && this.state.firstRender) {
            const n = e.nativeEvent.layout;
            const position = {
                  width: n.width,
                  height: n.height,
                  x: n.x,
                  y: n.y
            }
    console.log(position);
    this.setState({
         firstRender: false,          
         objLocation: this.state.objLocation.concat([position])
    });
  }
```

}

Comment: It could, but the one result of this is that `firstRender` is set to `false` after the first item is inserted into the array.

Answer (score 0):

According to the information provided by you, your onLayout function is called by the  component so its not included in the  component lifecycle process, so when the  component completes its lifecycle it goes into componentDidMount after mounting (which is not calling onLayout func) & thus changed the firstRender state to false and hence when you drag the component each time it goes from true to false.
I hope this explains

Comment: Maybe I'm miss-understanding the sequence of events, but what I think I've got happening is `=> 1. 'App'` is called => `2. 'Draggable'` children of app are called, passing the parent 'onLayout' function to child via 'props' `=> 3. 'props.onLayout'` is called in Draggable render providing 'e.nativeEvent' data in the callback `=> 4. parent 'onLayout' function` concatenates the position data to 'objLocation'. `=> 5. 'componentDidMount'` changes 'firstRender' ??`

Comment: Trying to get to grips with react-native, so it is possible my perception of what I'm doing vs what is actually happening is incorrect.

Comment: I just realized the mistake I made there and updated the question apologies onLayout shouldn't have been in the parent component

Comment: props.onLayout function is not a part of <View> component's life cycle so when <View> component mounting completed componentDidMount called and changed the state of firstRender from true to false and this all happens before going into onLayout function.

Comment: Ah ok, so once the most outer `<View/>` is mounted by `render()` in the parent component, the function moves on without waiting for callbacks to return data. `componentDidMount()`.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I've hacked this, to get it to work, so please correct me as to correct procedure.

This is the onLayout method from the `App`. I've included an `if` statement that checks if the new positions array length is equal too the dataArray length that the draggable items are based on.

It looks like this.

```
onLayout = (e) => {
  if ( this.state.objLocation.length != dataArray.length ) {
    if ( e ) {
      const n = e.nativeEvent.layout;
          const position = {
            width: n.width,
            height: n.height,
            x: n.x,
            y: n.y
          }
      console.log(position);
      this.setState({
        objLocation: this.state.objLocation.concat([position])
      });
    }
  }
}
```